# How to set ENV['INFO_PLIST'] for FastLane?

Tags: fastlane

Why Fastlane raise this error?

```
[13:21:24]: Error in your Fastfile at line 812
[13:21:24]:     810:    
[13:21:24]:     811:        def update_xcode_version(current_version_and_build_number)
[13:21:24]:  => 812:            info_plist_dir = File.expand_path(ENV['INFO_PLIST'], PROJECT_DIR)
[13:21:24]:     813:    
[13:21:24]:     814:            version = current_version_and_build_number.split('-')[0]
[13:21:24]: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do ?
I assume you have specified an environment variable called `INFO_PLIST` with the name of the plist, right?